# Are there conventions for signing JSON as a tree, to allow proofs of signed subtrees?

Tags: signature, protocol-design, hash-tree, jws

Given some JSON with a chosen encoding, you can obviously cryptographically-sign the whole thing as a binary blob.

However, it might be useful if the logical structure of the JSON-compatible object were leveraged to control what is signed, in such a way that you could later provide compact proofs that some subtree of the JSON object was signed (without necessarily providing the full JSON object).

For the purposes of illustration, assume the JSON object is a large dictionary, mapping short names to longer blobs, as might be constructed by the following Javascript.

```
json = { 'A': 'rfhserusliurslierfsieursiuebr',
         'B': '384ur3984hfe98r9e8hjf8ej4fj04',
         ...
         'Z': 'xcvubxudgoxduhf9xd88hxd9fybdf',
}
```

I'm hoping for some robust deterministic convention, already hammered out in a mature spec, for providing a "signature" of this object that does more than a plain signature-of-its-JSON-serialization.

Then, consider a 3rd party that has that signature, plus the full JSON, but only wants/needs to show that the original signer signed something containing:

```
subset = { 'B': '384ur3984hfe98r9e8hjf8ej4fj04', }
```

I'm hoping the convention also specifies how this 3rd party can construct a combination of that subset, the signature, and something else about the elided ranges – that still proves the original signer committed to just that subset.

It seems this might already exist – if not already for JSON, then for some other similar hierarchical object model.

One natural approach that 1st comes to mind would involve composing the keys/values/slots of the entire object into a hash tree, and then signing the root. With suitable tricks, this might allow the 3rd party to prove *any* `subset`, like the one above, in a compact (or even fixed-size) way. (But maybe there are other techniques, involving composable signatures, zk-proofs, redactable-hashing, etc - the goal is more important than the mechanism.)

Does anyone know of applicable conventions/standards/published-techniques? Just names or references of related prior work, for further searching/reading, would be great answers.

Comment: How is this question different from [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54953/555) ? When I looked at it, I found nothing existing, and concluded that the difficulty of the exercise is defining exactly what two JSON with the same content are.This is especially hairy for numbers.

Comment: Both questions give examples that are not strictly conforming JSON. Both allow to end enumerations with `,}` or `,]` where there should be no `,`. The present one quotes with `'` where that should be `"`. The other did not quote object tags. There is no indication that it is intentional in either. This raises the issue of if two object differing by the aforementioned details should have identical hash. I wish the question would be trimmed to specify purely standard JSON. It's complex enough !

Comment: While the other Q is related, & the @fgrieu sketch-of-a-possible-approach is interesting, they're not quite the same. Here, I'm requesting info about potentially-applicable existing conventions/standards. And while I suspect a hash tree might be involved, I'd be open to other constructions. (Accumulators? New combinable signature schemes?) Maybe there are none yet (given few responses so far), maybe they're just too obscure, or maybe they'll arrive soon. But for this question, a bespoke-in-another-StackExchange-answer rough-approach-outline wouldn't earn the same 'accepted' check that Q got.

Comment: Also, while JSON is the motivating/concrete case, as I mentioned, I'd be equally interested in conventions on other similar data structures. That is, this is a matter of data-structures & what cryptography might deliver the desired results, not really JS/JSON. By closing it as if "duplicate" or "answered", there's much less chance for someone who *does* know an applicable existing practice – perhaps even one that's novel since the question was asked, or since @fgrieu's research/attempt – to give a responsive answer.

Comment: Is the question about _signing an abstract tree so that it can be later provided compact proofs that some subtree is part of what's signed, without providing the rest of the tree_? It can be a fine new question, or an edit of this one (and not a dupe of the linked Q). Does leaf order matter? Are labeled leafs essential? I know no standard or reference (_only_ asking for one is off-topic). _"Given some JSON with a chosen encoding"_ ruined my reading of the question, making me focus on the difficulty of defining _part of a JSON tree_, and discrepancies of the examples w.r.t. JSON syntax.

Comment: Note that "given some JSON of a chosen encoding" is *not* the desired domain for an answer, but part of the motivating preamble – a trivial case against which my goal contrasts. The question is about "JSON objects", and all the excerpted examples are valid JavaScript that creates valid JSON objects. (I'd agree canonicalization-of-what-is-signed is likely a key part of any usable practice, but whether or not what-is-signed is valid JSON, or not, is an extra constraint on possible suggestions I'd rather leave open.)

Comment: An answer to your related and more-generic "signing an abstract tree..." reformulation would be of some interest – especially if it's a standard/in-use/named technique, and very especially if there's already some convention for its use with JSON-shaped-objects. (Where, specifically, leaf names matter but order doesn't, etc.) But I already understand that's *generically* possible, & could improvise an approach myself. I am asking experts here hoping to find established adaptable practices that have already survived some review/use, & are thus less likely to have spec/crypto flaws.

Comment: FWIW, since posting I learned of <https://github.com/benlaurie/objecthash>, which is *almost* what I was hoping to find. (And, if this question were re-opened, I'd post it as one useful relevant answer.) But my hunch remains there may already exist a better cryptographic practice, that wouldn't require its large/clunky `"**REDACTED**...` inserts, nor reveal as much of the object's structure, hidden in some paper or project that just isn't well known. So I'd still be open to other answers.

Comment: There's a policy (or at least a [line of thought](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/324/555)) that pure reference requests are off-topic. While your examples may be valid JavaScript, they are not [valid JSON](https://www.json.org/) (wrong sort of quote, extra comma at end). I suggest that you simplify and specify your actual problem to the max: from JSON eliminate array, number, true, false and null, assume a canonical encoding of strings; if it is desirable or not that proof of being in the tree reveals where in the tree; if leak of tree structure is an issue..

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that the examples were never intended to be legal JSON, but rather Javascript for constructing JSON-compatible objects. Thanks for the pointer to the discussion about reference requests; however, I believe this question is more like the "fine question" examples there – requests for pointers to work that solves a specific problem – rather than the kind of open-ended questions disfavored there. (*Zero* answers in almost 2 years is more indicative of "too specific" than "overbroad".)

Comment: I did not vote to close, and (now) see that the question is not a dupe. I still think that the question is too imprecise. It is unclear: which segment of the question's text form the actual question; if it is concerned about potentially deep trees, or only list of tag-value pairs as in the example; what's the intended meaning of _"some subtree of the JSON object was signed"_ (is it _some subtree was in what was signed_?); is a value without its tag a subtree? do we get a subtree by removing a tag:value?; is it desirable or not that the proof demonstrates/revals the position of the subtree?

Comment: There is now an effort to canonicalize JSON, I think solving some of the issues. See [RFC 8785](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8785.html).